# Have switch statement's default case call a prior case?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, switch-statement, control-flow

Whenever I use a `switch-case` statement – 9 times out of 10 – the final `default` case is almost always that of a case above it.

ie.

```
// WebView Observers
switch webView {
    case webView:
        webViewURLObserver = webView.observe(\.url, options: .new) { [weak self] webView, change in
            let url = "\(String(describing: change.newValue))"
            self?.urlDidChange(urlString: url) }
    case customizerWebView:
        customizerURLObserver = customizerWebView.observe(\.url, options: .new) { [weak self] webView, change in
            let url = "\(String(describing: change.newValue))"
            self?.customizerURLDidChange(urlString: url) }
    case default:
        webViewURLObserver = webView.observe(\.url, options: .new) { [weak self] webView, change in
        let url = "\(String(describing: change.newValue))"
        self?.urlDidChange(urlString: url) }
    }
```

Is there a way to have the `default` case just reference one of the already-existing cases?

```
// What I'm trying to accomplish
switch webView {
    case webView:
        [webView Observer Code]
        ...
    case customizerWebView:
        [customizerWebView Observer Code]
        ...
    case default:
        switch.case = webView || switch.case = 0
    }
```

Comment: Why not move your first case to your default? I'm assuming what you're attempting to do is say `if no other cases match, default to the first case.` If you're doing that simply removing the first case and setting it to the default would fulfill that goal.

Comment: What about `fallthrough`: `switch webView{ case customizerWebView: ...; case webView: fallthrough; case default: ... }`? https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html#ID140

Comment: @xTwisteDx Does it not work similar to if-else statements where it'll check all values in order? I always assumed setting `default: [firstCaseCode]; case secondCase: [secondCaseCode]` would result in _else-then-if_ behaviour.

Comment: Thanks @Larme, looking into it now! This `if-else`-type syntax will work just fine! But I wonder if, as mentioned by @xTwisteDx, you can set the initial `default` case at the top and have it act as the first statement. It would get rid of a line or two of code. However, the `fallthrough` code almost suggests that the switch checks in order from top to bottom.

Comment: The way that it functions is exactly how you're saying it checks line-by-line from top to bottom sequentially. You can't put default at the top but you can take the "copied" code and simply place it in the default statement. Basically, if you use a switch statement then you need to cover all possible conditions, the default is there to cover anything not in range of the conditions. There are many times when I'm using Switch statements where I leave the "Default" blank or use "Fallthrough." It depends on what you're trying to accomplish. Based on this post simply removing and putting it default

Comment: Because `default` in a `switch` will be: "any case", you can put it at the top but since there is an "order", it's useless, other cases won't be triggered, and you get a compiler error message. "Additional 'case' blocks cannot appear after the 'default' block of a 'switch'". Think it as a `if (caseA) else if (caseB) else if (true// default) {}`, so moving the `else if (true)` at first...

Comment: With code: https://pastebin.com/DP7YzUmX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution is to use [fallthrough](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html#ID140).

Instead of thinking:

> In case of "default": do something of target case

Think it in the other way:

> In case of target case, do "default".

```
switch webView {
case customizerWebView:
    customizerURLObserver = customizerWebView.observe(\.url, options: .new) { [weak self] webView, change in
        let url = "\(String(describing: change.newValue))"
        self?.customizerURLDidChange(urlString: url) }
case webView:
        fallthrough
case default:
    webViewURLObserver = webView.observe(\.url, options: .new) { [weak self] webView, change in
    let url = "\(String(describing: change.newValue))"
    self?.urlDidChange(urlString: url) }
}
```

Or as, pointed by [@xTwiteDx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60934285/have-switch-statements-default-case-call-a-prior-case/60934692?noredirect=1#comment107806448_60934285), you can remove the lines `case webView: fallthrough` if you don't do a specific code before `fallthrough`. It's up to you, how you are comfortable with you code, how to explicit or not cases.

Comment: Thanks @Larme, I wasn't aware that `fallthrough` even existed! Very useful! Quick side-question, would you happen to know why I can't create a function for initializing the observers? The above code works just fine when put directly into the `viewDidLoad` method; however, when I create a function from it in the `viewDidLoad` – ie. `observeWebView(webView)`, and then put the switch statement above in `func observeWebView(_ sender: WKWebView)`, it will not make it to the observer code (tested with print statement `... self?.urlDidChange(urlString: url); print("Did we make it?") }`).

Comment: In another question. Right now, I don't know why it doesn't work, but I might be missing an info, or assuming other infos...